# Open specific tab based on the current month

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am building an Employee Recognition/Employee of the month website and I organize the results with Month tabs - Jan, Feb, March etc. However,  I would like that the tab of the current month opens automatically when the page is loaded eg during March, the March tab opens and after 12 am on 1st of April, the active tab should change automatically and open April when loaded. I used the following jquery:

```
 $(function(){
    var date = new Date();
    var months = date.getMonth();
    date.setFullYear(2020);
    document.getElementsByClassName('.wrapper').innerHTML = date;

    if (months == 0 || months == 6) {
        $('a[aria-controls="wrapper"]').closest('li').addClass('active');
        $('a[aria-controls="wrapper"]').closest('li').removeClass('active');
    }
    else {
        $('a[aria-controls="wrapper"]').closest('li').addClass('active');
        $('a[aria-controls="wrapper"]').closest('li').removeClass('active');
    }
});
```

Have you used datepicker for this purpose? Do you have any idea why the code is not working? Or do you have any other ideas how can I execute this?

HTML:

```
<section class="wrapper">
    <ul class="tabs">
    <li class="active">Jan</li>
    <li type="date">Feb</li>
    <li type="date">March</li>
    <li type="date">April</li>
    <li type="date">May</li>
    <li type="date">June</li>
    <li type="date">July</li>
    <li type="date">Aug</li>
    <li type="date">Sept</li>   
    <li type="date">Oct</li>
    <li type="date">Nov</li>
    <li type="date">Dec</li>
    </ul>

    <ul class="tab__content">
        <li class="active">
            <div class="content__wrapper" type="date">
        <div id="cards">
```

Comment: your `if`/`else` block do the exact same thing. Plus they do nothing as they just add and then remove a class on the same elements. Please post the relevenat HTML so we can understand what you mean by `tab`

Comment: @Vlastimir you wanna edit the post and add the html there , currently the html isn't readable

Comment: Here it is @AbdullahAbid